# How to build plain Mono for Android?

Tags: c#, android, mono, arm

I am currently using Mono on Raspberry PI. I know there is a commercial full featured Mono for Android developed by Xamarin and that there is also free limited trial version.

Is there still an open source version of `plain` Mono for Android? I mean a plain version like for Raspberry PI -- without Android SDK, just for console applications, etc.

I have found: https://github.com/koush/androidmono.
But it seems that it is no longer developed.

Is it possible to build plain Mono for Android?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want Mono for Android on the Raspberry Pi? The "full" Mono works fine for console apps etc. on the Pi. In case you didn't know: MfA/Xamarin is a stripped down version of Mono, with stuff like WinForms, System.Web etc. removed which don't make sense on Android, not the other way round.

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger I do not want to run Mono for Android on Raspberry PI, but plain Mono (like the version on Raspberry PI) on Android. (I do not need the Android SDK integration.)

Comment: ah, I seemed to have misread your question, sorry. I'm not aware of a maintained version of Mono for Android other than Xamarin.

Comment: Building Mono for ARM: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/arm/

Comment: I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450508/building-mono-with-android-ndk-standalone-toolchain-android-ndk-r8e @Skall put it as an answer. (maybe it could be a community wiki?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building Mono for ARM is described here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/arm/

Comment: This is also a very old solution. Are you sure it still works for the latest mono?