# How does one compile mono for Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

Are there modern and official instructions / guides on compiling mono for Android/ARM? I believe the ones I've found to be outdated / incomplete, [as do others on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26989377/10498104). If there aren't, would someone be so kind as to share how they do it?

I'm motivated to compile mono for Android because I have encountered something I believe to be a potential bug. I need to be able to confirm it, however. I would like to be able to examine and modify the code, see if the issue is resolved, and contribute a change if possible.

In terms of compiling Mono for Windows and Linux, I can do it just fine and have done so a couple of times. Unfortunately [the documentation for doing so on Android (ARM)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/arm/) appears outdated. In particular, the Debian packages mentioned fail to install, the cross-compilation chain recommended hasn't been updated since 2011, etc. I'm assuming the steps on the mono site are outdated. If they are *not*, and these instructions are valid, then I will have to post a different question about the issues I'm encountering whilst compiling as it just doesn't appear to work.

Thanks.

Comment: `Xamarin.Android` source: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/README.md#building-from-source

Comment: 1. Mono for Android is long dead. 2. If you meant Xamarin.Android, it is dying soon as MAUI is now in production. Microsoft won't fix any issue there. 3. MAUI is part of .NET Core, so its runtime source code is in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. I appreciate the responses, despite feeling a tad silly.